# Do I need :presence=>true on my model if I have :length=>{:minimum=>1,:maximum=>255}?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Is having both :presence=>true and length validation on my rails model redundant?  Or is there a reason to have both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those validations do not do the same.The only difference is that if you just leave the validation checking the length you could still fill the field with spaces (from 1 to 255).
With the presence validation spaces are not taken a character

Comment: Ahhh. Good to know...Going to go give it a spin.